# comparison operator is not working in twig

Tags: php, symfony

- problem in comparing dates  in twig.
- case  if event is ongoing or is about to begin within 7 days.

twig code

```
 {% set  event_startdate=data.detailes.data.event.event_startdate|date("d-m-Y")%}
 {% set  event_enddate=data.detailes.data.event.event_enddate|date("d-m-Y") %}
 {% set upcoming_days =daysdiff(event_startdate)|date('d-m-y') %}
 {% set stdate= "now"|date('d-m-y') %}

   {% if event_startdate >stdate and event_startdate < upcoming_days  %}

 // condition true
     {% else %}
      // condition false 
    {%endif %}
```

acmextension.php (custom function)

```
 public function daysdiff($date)
{

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'));

return $date;
}
```

- date are as follows :

  ```
    14-11-2015(event startdate) ,17-06-15(current date) and 21-11-15(7 days addded in startdate).
  ```

problem

- compare operators is not working in twig.

Comment: Comparing dates in `d/m/Y` format isn't sensible, because you're comparing strings.... which is the greater `31/01/2015` or `01/12/2020`? Either compare the raw timestamps, or use a format like `Y-m-d` for a string comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to not convert the dates to string with twigs date filter

e.g

```
 {% set upcoming_days =daysdiff(event_startdate) %}
```

instead of

```
 {% set upcoming_days =daysdiff(event_startdate)|date("d.m.y") %}
```